# JavaScript Server Side event issue

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events, echo

My server-side event is not calling the jplayers function at all. It only displays that I have the one JavaScript error below but continues to execute `start.php` but the events never get called. The `number1` does get logged. This error appears but cant tell whats wrong:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ...

```js
var source = new EventSource('start.php');
var plr;
source.addEventListener("player", jplayers, false);
source.addEventListener("nplayer", nplayers, false);

function nplayers(e) {
    alert(e.data);
    var pingev = document.getElementById("nplayers");
    pingev.innerHTML = e.data;
    plr = e.data;
}
function jplayers(e){
    alert(e.data);
    var pingev = document.getElementById("jplayers");
    pingev.innerHTML = e.data;
    plr = e.data;
}
```

```php
$result = $dbconn->query($query);
$number1 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
logMsg($number1);
echo "event: player\n";
echo 'data: ' .$number1. '';
echo "\n\n";
```

Comment: Does your console contain any errors?

Comment: None except the one i mentioned before the code

Comment: Try loading the php page in a tab on its own. See if the page actually does what you expect then. If you can't get the resource it's probably 500'ing. Also check the network pane of your fave debugger for a response and see what that is.

Comment: It is doing what I want when i loaded the php on its own and it did what i expected it to. And I have been looking at the network panel and everything looked as it should.

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help though

Comment: You can add answers to your own questions